# Rollup.js is generating sourcemap but it is not available in the application which is consuming it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollupjs, source-maps

I have created React wrapper around web-components to create a component library using TypeScript for type safety and Rollup to bundle it. Rollup is bundling and generating source map but the React App which is consuming this library is not loading the source map.

Rollup version 3.21.0

I have checked chrome settings and that looks ok.

The consuming app should load the source-map file

Comment: I figured it out. I just need to restart the server after adding sourceMap: true in the component lib tsconfig.ts file. Please make sure you have files available in sources and sourcesContent array in generated source map files.